# Transform pgfplot coordinates; "axis cs" but for \pic Radii

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates, axis

I am trying to use `angle radius` in `\pic` without units, but instead with the axis coordinate system. In a sense the same as `axis cs` does for coordinates, but just for this radius.

I have looked through the documentation, which states

> Since  drawing  circles  and  ellipses  inside  of  an  axis  is  a  common  use-case, pgfplots automatically communicates  its  coordinate  system  transformations  to  TikZ.

As it seems this is not the case for `\pic`, only for circles and ellipses.

I also stumbled upon `\pgfplotstransformcoordinatex` which I think does what I want. However I could not achieve the desired result (coordinates were way off).

Can someone explain how I can achieve this? Thank you very much in advance, any input is greatly appreciated.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.75\textwidth,
            height=0.75\textwidth,
            xmin=-1500,
            xmax=1500,
            ymin=-1500,
            ymax=1500,
            ytick distance=500,
            xtick distance=500,
            grid=both
            ]

            \coordinate[] (a) at (axis cs: 500,0);
            \coordinate[] (b) at (axis cs: 0,0);
            \coordinate[] (c) at (axis cs: -500,0);

            \pic[draw, angle radius = 1.25 cm]{angle=a--b--c}; % Works, but I want:
            %\pic[draw, angle radius = 500]{angle=a--b--c}; % angle radius is not transformed
        
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: as I know, scaling is implicit in pgfplots! by the way, which figure do you want to obtain?

Comment: @BlackMild Sorry I don't follow. What does it mean that scaling is implicit? I want to achieve the figure I have attached to my question, but I'd like to do so by the command that is currently commented out, so I can specify the arc size in "plot coordinates" not by an absolute value in cm.

Comment: try this `\draw (a) arc(0:180:500);` Using plain TikZ is a good choice for explicit scaling